# Enigma between Colleagues (Part1)

Tags: number-sequence

With a colleague, we tried to create enigma to challenge ourselves.

Here is our first try, hope you will enjoy it.

> 4 = 2
>
> 12 = 3
>
> 19 = 3
>
> 24 = 4
>
> 47 = 5
>
> 50 = ?

Hint 1 :

> 1987 = 10

Don't hesitate to comment some advice for the following enigma :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll go with

> 50 = **1**.

Surely the number on the right must be

> the length of the number in Roman numerals.

Double checking everything:

> ```
>  4  = IV    = 2
>  12 = XII   = 3
>  19 = XIX   = 3
>  24 = XXIV  = 4
>  47 = XLVII = 5
> ```

And finally

> `1987 = MCMLXXXVII = 10.`

Yup, seems to match nicely.

Comment: Was it too easy ? How to improve it ? Did you use the hint ?

Comment: It was pretty much in the sweet spot of "easy, but rewarding to solve", well done! Yes, I took a peek at the hint, which gave a pretty good idea of how large the numbers were going to get. On this site, it's usual to withhold any actual hints (that aren't really a part of the question) until the next day, so any hints posted along with the question kind of get read automatically. Maybe I should try to get rid of that habit, come to think of it :-)